# Get IPconfig info android

Tags: java, android, networking

Im developing an android app, and one of the activities shows an IPconfig list. I am using the following code for getting the info:

```
public String   s_dns1 ;
    public String   s_dns2;     
    public String   s_gateway;  
    public String   s_ipAddress;    
    public String   s_leaseDuration;    
    public String   s_netmask;  
    public String   s_serverAddress;
    DhcpInfo d;
    WifiManager wifii;

 wifii= (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        d=wifii.getDhcpInfo();
        s_dns1="DNS 1: "+String.valueOf(d.dns1);
        s_dns2="DNS 2: "+String.valueOf(d.dns2);    
        s_gateway="Default Gateway: "+String.valueOf(d.gateway);    
        s_ipAddress="IP Address: "+String.valueOf(d.ipAddress); 
        s_leaseDuration="Lease Time: "+String.valueOf(d.leaseDuration);     
        s_netmask="Subnet Mask: "+String.valueOf(d.netmask);    
        s_serverAddress="Server IP: "+String.valueOf(d.serverAddress);

        info= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info1);
        info.setText("\n"+s_dns1+"\n"+s_dns2+"\n"+s_gateway+"\n"+s_ipAddress+"\n"+s_leaseDuration+"\n"+s_netmask+"\n"+s_serverAddress);
```

In the emulator i get the following:

```
DNS1:0
DNS2:0
Default gateway:0
IP address:0
Lease time:0
Subnet mask:-1
Server IP:0
```

However, when i test the APK on my Galaxy tab GT-P1000 i get the following:

```
DNS1:16820416
DNS2:0
Default gateway:16820416
IP address:33597632
Lease time:86400
Subnet mask:16777215
Server IP:16820416
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: How do i do that? - im pretty new to java+android

Comment: It's StackExchange related: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Comment: what's your question? does emulator support wifi service? I doubt.. so you will not get that info. on emulator.

Comment: No, when i tested on my Galaxy tab it came up with this:

DNS1:16820416
DNS2:0
Default gateway:16820416
IP address:33597632
Lease time:86400
Subnet mask:16777215
Server IP:16820416

Comment: @AlexOGden no it actually appears to be giving plausibly correct figures which you are failing to display in the form you are used to.  As for the Emulator, last I checked it "emulated" a 3g connection rather than a wifi one.

Answer (score 0):

All of those dnsinfo members are IP address and they use an int to store the address. You'll have to convert it to a string.
Lazy man's way:

```
byte[] ba = BigInteger.valueOf(ip).toByteArray();
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ba);
String s = address.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks, how do i implement this?

Comment: This is how you would decode d.dns1 to s_dns1. It turns the IP stored as an int into a string.